# Hyperledger Certifcate Reenroll command not work

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Hello Can you help me to find a way to renew the certitifcate expire date  I have serach alot but didno't find any good help
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$HOME/fabric-ca/clients/peer1
fabric-ca-client reenroll

Answer (score 0):

export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$HOME/fabric-ca/clients/peer1
Set FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME every time you enroll the any peer or admin or user because it will create fabric-ca-client-config.yaml which are require to re-enroll certificate before it will expire